# How to go about to create general messages

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor and coming from a Laravel enviroment I got stuck on creating a template for general messages (error, success, info, warning etc).

This is my layout. As you can see, when an event occurs and something goes wrong (or succeed) I want to show the message.

```
<template name="layout">
<div class="ui grid">
    {{>header}}
</div>
<div class="ui stackable page grid">
    {{#if somestatement}}
    {{>messages}}
    {{/if}}
    {{>yield}}
</div>
</template>
```

For example my login event:

```
Template.login.events({
    'submit #login-form' : function(e, template) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = template.find('#login-email').value,
            password = template.find('#password').value;

        Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){
            if(err)
            {
                /*here i want to return the error and type to the template */

            }
            else
            {
                Route.go('dashboard');
            }
            return;
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

The message template:

```
<template name="messages">
    <div class="ui {{type}} message">
        <i class="close icon"></i>
        <div class="header">{{headerMessage}}</div>
        {{message}}
    </div>
</template>
```

But I have no clue on how to go about it. Tried tons of stuff and this seems like a super easy thing to do, so im probably just not read enough about it. But any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `flash-messages` package. It's designed to be used with bootstrap and provides the ability to show various types of messages. There are lots of examples in the README on atmosphere.

https://atmospherejs.com/mrt/flash-messages

Comment: Thanks. This will be my temporary solution til I figure out how to do this on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out `s-alert` package :) http://s-alert.meteor.com 
It has very good documentation and demo website: http://s-alert-demo.meteor.com

Atmosphere (over 800 downloads :) ): https://atmospherejs.com/juliancwirko/s-alert

Answer (score 1):

If want to do it yourself and you happen to have the "Discover Meteor" book, there's a good way of showing error messages in the 'Errors' chapter.

I use it on my current site, it shows a Growl-like flash message at the top-right of the screen. Could be adapted easily for info/warnings colour coding.

Comment: Actually I do have the book. Never had the time to read it properly. Thanks for the tip, will read and figure it out :)

Comment: Yes, take a look, they make it dead easy to do what you want to do.